Quantizing a `Serial` tendorflow model throws `Value Error`
I have the following Tensorflow model that I want to quantize:
model = Sequential([
    Input(shape=input_shape),
    LSTM(lstm_units_1, return_sequences=True),
    Dropout(dropout_rate),
    LSTM(lstm_units_2, return_sequences=False),
    Dropout(dropout_rate),
    Dense(4, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=10, restore_best_weights=True)
model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(model_path, monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=False, mode='min')

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, 
                    epochs=epochs, 
                    batch_size=batch_size, 
                    validation_split=0.2, 
                    callbacks=[early_stopping],
                    verbose=1)

model.save(model_path)

I am trying to perform the quantization like this:
annotated_model = tfmot.quantization.keras.quantize_annotate_model(model)

with tfmot.quantization.keras.quantize_scope():
    quant_aware_model = tfmot.quantization.keras.quantize_apply(annotated_model)

quant_aware_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

But I am receiving this error: ValueError: `to_annotate` can only be a `keras.Model` instance. Use the `quantize_annotate_layer` API to handle individual layers. You passed an instance of type: Sequential.
Trying to quantize each layer as the error suggest didn't work for me as well with another value error about LSTM layers not being accepted as inputs.
annotated_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tfmot.quantization.keras.quantize_annotate_layer(layer)
    for layer in model.layers
])

What is the correct way to quantize the particular model I am using here?

Rewrite your TensorFlow model in pure TensorFlow, or alternatively, use Keras. However, do not mix the two, as this can lead to numerous errors. I recommend using Keras for everything.
Example in Keras

import keras
from keras import layers
from keras import ops
import numpy as np

# Define Sequential model with 3 layers
model = keras.Sequential(
    [
        layers.Dense(2, activation="relu", name="layer1"),
        layers.Dense(3, activation="relu", name="layer2"),
        layers.Dense(4, name="layer3"),
    ]
)

# Compile the model
model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss='mean_squared_error',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

# Example data for training
x_train = np.random.random((100, 3)).astype('float32')
y_train = np.random.random((100, 4)).astype('float32')

# Train the model
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=32)

# Convert the model to TensorFlow Lite with post-training quantization to float16
import tensorflow as tf

# Convert the model to a TensorFlow Lite model
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.target_spec.supported_types = [tf.float16]
tflite_model = converter.convert()

# Save the quantized model
with open("model_quantized_f16.tflite", "wb") as f:
    f.write(tflite_model)

